# How to get Spring application context and pass it to methods of other class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, singleton, autowired

I have MongoRepository bean in my Spring Boot app that I have declared somewhere in the app as @Autowired. I want to pass this variable as a parameter to function belonging to separate Java library that I'm using (contains Generic type). Is it possible to achieve this? Can I send the bean like that?

Or, is it possible to get the App Context somehow and pass that to the method of the other library?

Comment: Could you be slightly more elaborative, Try adding code snippets as well that clearly depicts the requirement / problem / issue.

Comment: You can get the application context by classic Spring injection when defining a Bean/Service/Component, ... for example ```@Bean public MyBeanType createBean(ApplicationContext ctx) {...}``` you can then invoke your other library and pass it the variable as parameter of an expecting method. However I am very curious to know the context for wanting to do something like this. Same with passing the Bean to a separate java library. Is it not possible to rather pass the result of a call? A DTO for instance...?